# Loading http content on https domain

Tags: django, http, heroku, https, web-deployment

We have created a website which is served right now on Heroku. This website has a search bar in the navbar and I wanted to use Freefind search service for the backend. The search result I receive from it are all over the HTTP server and Heroku server will not load it.

I want them to work fine just as they work on localhost. What can I do?

The app is Django based and I tried to google custom search but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load most HTTP content on HTTPS domains. Loading HTTP images is fine, but is still discouraged. This is called [mixed content blocking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content), which is a browser's feature.

The only thing you can do is to find out if freefind's search service supports HTTPS. You can try changing the URL to `https://search.freefind.com/...` and see if it works. Or contact freefind and ask them if they support HTTPS. If they don't support HTTPS, you have to find a different company's search service.